# CakePHP - Router::url() generating url relative to current page

Tags: cakephp, aws-lambda, cakephp-3.0, php-7.4, bref

I'm trying to replace all of my static routes with the CakePHP 3.8 `Router::url()` method.

On my local environment, when accessing the the below code from the `manage/lender-products/read/2` route, I get the expected results of `/manage/lenders` from the below code:

```php
\Cake\Routing\Router::url(['controller' => 'Lenders', 'action' => 'index'])
```

However, on production (bref.sh/AWS Lambda/PHP 7.4), I get the unexpected result of `/manage/lender-products/read/manage/lenders`.

It appears that in my production environment, the URL is being generated and is including the current pages url in the end result.

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not set a custom base path for the `App.base` config option, CakePHP will try to figure the possible base path out on its own, based on `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, so it's likely that one or both of these contain unexpected values in your AWS environment.

The simple fix would be to manually set the base path in your `config/app.php`. If your application doesn't actually live in a public subdirectory (ie in case `webroot` is your document root), then you should set the path to an empty string, otherwise provide the path, like `/my/app` (with a leading slash, but without a trailing slash!).

See also

- **[Cookbook > Configuration > General Configuration](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/configuration.html#general-configuration)**